# implementing typelist replace operation using variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, typelist

I'm trying to implement a ReplaceAll metafunction for variadic template version of typelists  (inspired by [Modern C++ Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design)) and so far I could achieve the desired outcome with the following code:

```
template <typename... Elements> struct Typelist {};

//
// helper metafunction to set "Head" of typelist
//
template <typename TList, typename T> struct PushFrontT;

template <typename... Elements, typename T>
struct PushFrontT<Typelist<Elements...>, T> {
    using Result = Typelist<T, Elements...>;
};

//
// metafunction to replace all occurences of "T" with "U"
//
template <typename TList, typename T, typename U> struct ReplaceAll;

template <typename T, typename U>
struct ReplaceAll<Typelist<>, T, U> {
    using Result = Typelist<>;
};

template <typename... Tail, typename T, typename U>
struct ReplaceAll<Typelist<T, Tail...>, T, U> {
    using Result = typename PushFrontT<
        typename ReplaceAll<Typelist<Tail...>, T, U>::Result, U
    >::Result;
};

template <typename Head, typename... Tail, typename T, typename U>
struct ReplaceAll<Typelist<Head, Tail...>, T, U> {
    using Result = typename PushFrontT<
        typename ReplaceAll<Typelist<Tail...>, T, U>::Result, Head
    >::Result;
};
```

Which returns a typelist in the form of `Typelist<T1, T2, T3>` (effectively replacing all occurrences of type `T` with the target type `U`).

Now the problem is that when I try to not use the helper metafunction `PushFrontT`, a nested typelist structure would be created in the form of `Typelist<T1, Typelist<T2, Typelist<T3, Typelist<>>>>` which is incorrect (despite replacing all instances of `T` with `U`).

The code for the incorrect version is as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct ReplaceAll<Typelist<>, T, U> {
    using Result = Typelist<>;
};

template <typename... Tail, typename T, typename U>
struct ReplaceAll<Typelist<T, Tail...>, T, U> {
    using Result = Typelist<U,
        typename ReplaceAll<Typelist<Tail...>, T, U>::Result
    >;
};

template <typename Head, typename... Tail, typename T, typename U>
struct ReplaceAll<Typelist<Head, Tail...>, T, U> {
    using Result = Typelist<Head,
        typename ReplaceAll<Typelist<Tail...>, T, U>::Result
    >;
};
```

Based on my limited knowledge of variadic templates, I think the additional `Typelist` is a side effect of a [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) but I'm not sure.
Here is a simple test program to check the aforementioned code:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main () {
    using tlist = Typelist<int, char, int, double>;

    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
        typename ReplaceAll<tlist, int, long>::Result,
        Typelist<long, char, long, double>>::value,
        "Incorrect typelist!"
    );

    return(0);
}
```

In short, my question is how should I get rid of the excessive nested `Typelist`s without using an outside helper metafunction such as `PushFrontT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might simplify your code and get rid of the recursion with

```
template <typename TList, typename T, typename U> struct ReplaceAll;

template <typename ... Ts, typename T, typename U>
struct ReplaceAll<Typelist<Ts...>, T, U>
{
    using Result = Typelist<std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<Ts, T>, U, Ts>...>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r831v7o19)